# Last element of previous page come as first element of next page in Sequelize pagination

Tags: pagination, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am using MySQL as the database for Sequelize pagination. I am getting the previous page's last element as the next page's first element.

```
exports.searchProductCategories = (body, username, shopId) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let searchText = body.searchText.toLowerCase();
    let limit = body.limit;
    let offset = body.offset;
    Category.findAndCountAll({
        where: {
            [Sequelize.Op.or]:[
                {name: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('LOWER', Sequelize.col(KEY_NAME_COLUMN)), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%')},
                {description: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('LOWER', Sequelize.col(KEY_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN)), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%')}
            ],
            [Sequelize.Op.and]:[
                {shopId: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col(KEY_SHOP_ID_COLUMN), Sequelize.Op.eq, shopId)}
            ]
        },
        order: [
            [KEY_NAME_COLUMN, 'ASC']
        ],
        offset: offset,
        limit: limit
      }).then(result => {
        resolve ({ [KEY_STATUS]: 1, [KEY_MESSAGE]: "Categories listed successfully", [KEY_DATA]: result.rows, [KEY_TOTAL_COUNT]: result.count });
    }).catch(error => { 
        reject ({ [KEY_STATUS]: 0, [KEY_MESSAGE]: "Categories list failed" + error });
    });
})
}
```

For the above code, I give

```
{
"searchText": "cat",
"limit": 2,
"offset": 0
}
```

Then I am getting 2 items. Next, I give

```
{
"searchText": "cat",
"limit": 2,
"offset": 1
}
```

Then I am getting the previous page's last element as current page's first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate offset by using page and limit
e.g:

```
    page = 1 // for first page
    offset = (page - 1) * limit   // for the first page it skips (1 - 1) * 2 = 0 records and show 2(limits) records
```

For the second page

```
limit = 2
page = 2
offset = (2-1)*2 = 2 // so it skips 2 records and show next 2 records
```